# How to get eclipse to mark where a for loop or if statement begins

Tags: eclipse, lines, jgrasp

I used JGrasp for a while, and now, while I realize Eclipse is MUCH Better, there is one thing I love in JGrasp, it would always mark where a for loop or if statement went to (ended.)

You can accomplish sort of the same things by highlighting a bracket in eclipse, but this is not efficient, and still then it only highlights the other bracket. What I'm looking for are the lines that you see directly to the left of the code in this picture.

(Sorry, I'm new, can't post pictures yet. But its just imgur.)

i.stack.imgur.c o m/KWtqI.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can use EditBox and customize it as you wish. http://editbox.sourceforge.net/